# Delete first row in Excel Workbook - Object Reference required error c#

Tags: c#, excel, object

I have been using the "Code Project" and "Stackoverflow" to create a script which will delete the first row of a specified excel workbook.

I am having an issue with line 13 "Range.EntireRow;" with the error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property Range.Entire.Row

Please see the script I have created below;

```
        public void DeleteRows(string workbookPath)
    {

        // New Excel Application 
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        //Open WorkBook 
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath,
                0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
                true, false, 0, true, false, false);

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;
        string currentSheet = "Sheet1";
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(currentSheet);

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range excelCell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "A1");
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range row = Range.EntireRow; //ERROR Line
        row.Delete(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDirection.xlUp);
```

Any advice on how to fix this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First guess would be rather than Range.EntireRow you need excelCell.EntireRow.. "Range" wouldnt know which range to pick

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refer to the `Cells` of the `Range` to get the entire row:

`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range row = excelCell.Cells.EntireRow`

or even omitting the `Cells` should work as well:

`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range row = excelCell.EntireRow`

[MSDN Range.EntireRow Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-entirerow-property-excel)

Answer (score 0):

You should use: `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range row = excelCell.EntireRow;`